# Alternative to selenium for creating bot

Tags: c#, selenium, bots

I want to create a simple bot using C# that will do a few simple things for user. Log into a site, go to the needed page, check if "post" was up for over 15 minutes and if so then edit the post and finish editing.
So I know I can do this using selenium with PhantomJS which will make it look like it is a bot that runs on its own, but obviously a hidden browser will be going in background. Is there alternative I could choose that would make the bot more efficient? Or is this bad from me that I could do this without using hidden we browser? What discourage me about using selenium and phantomJS is that I bought a little script written in Python which did almost the same thing, but I actually had to download some packages using "cmd" to make it work. (Don't remember right now what packages) and also the script was not in exe, so I had to "execute" it every time. Would using exe with C# fix that problem? And is there another way to do that kind of bot?

Comment: Microsoft UI Automation

Comment: Oh thanks. I will read about it when I get home. Could You just tell me I would need to use PhantomJs with this as well? Because I fell like it is needed to start a browser in the background to make it work?